# "Up" button which scrolls page to the top

Tags: scrolling

There is a kind of "tradition" on Russian web and I rarely see that on Western websites.

They add a huge (from top to bottom of window) "Up" button which scrolls page to the top after click. So, basically it duplicates the Home key on a keyboard — standard key everyone has.

Almost every major Russian website (social networks and media) implements this "Up" button one way or another.

The reason why they do that I suppose is that huge part of users doesn't know about the Home key or/and they find it much easier to click on huge button than press something on a keyboard.

Question is: Why they want users to go back at the top?

Please share your thoughts and suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't knew about that practice in russian sites.

Comment: Not every keyboard has a Home key. Apple laptops haven't had a labelled Home key for years, though the shortcut for it (Fn+Left) works if you happen to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

One common reason to want to go back to the top is to use the sidebar or top bar navigation, assuming they don't remain on screen as you scroll down.

Another reason with social media sites in particular is that they often add new stories to the top of the page in real time, but they don't auto-scroll the page back to the top as that would obviously be disruptive. (Though they do often pop up a "New Stories" link or similar that you can click to do the same thing, but that is a relatively recent phenomenon.)

Other than that, it's probably just a cultural/consistency thing; some Russian websites probably just implement it because that's what other Russian websites do, even on websites where it's not particularly useful.